# jquery mobile, issue when changing page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Inside my jquery mobile website I'm sending from footer textinput request to the controller which sends back json data back to the view as popup window (data inside this popup window is rendered using jstemplate).

Everything works as expected but when I change page request is passed to the controller but popup window not showing.

from my js function I'm sending

```
 $("#myDataPopUp").popup("open").enhanceWithin();
```

and inside _Layout.cshtml

```
<div id="myDataPopUp" data-role="popup" class="ui-content" data-theme="a" />
```

Again, everything works fine until I change page (since code is inside _Layout) it should work on other pages as well.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you using _single page_ or _multi-page_? When do you call the popup? Is it dynamically created?

Comment: I'm using multi page. Popup is called from js function which injects json data returned from controller. If you need more info please ask.

Comment: Popup is inside another page when you call it?

Comment: @Omar, nope, it's inside Layout, which is master page for all pages.

Comment: Place it outside any page, make it an external popup that can be accessed from any page any time. But you have to initialize it manually one time. `$(function () { $("id").popup().enhanceWithin(); });`

Comment: @omar please post this with detailed instruction and I will accept as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery Mobile 1.4, I do recommend using *External Popup* which can be accessed from any page. An *External Popup* should be placed outside any *page* div `data-role="page"` and then it should be *initialized* manually.

#### External Popup:

```
<div data-role="popup">
  <!-- contents -->
</div>

<div data-role="page">
  <!-- contents -->
</div>
```

#### Initialize External Popup:

If the Popup contains other *jQM widgets*, you need to *initialize* those widgets as well by calling `.enhanceWithin()`. Otherwise, `.popup()` is enough.

```
$(function () {
  $("#popupID").popup().enhanceWithin();
});
```

#### Open/Close Popup:

- Dynamically

  ```
  /* to enhance jQM widgets inside popup, if any */  
  $("#popupID").popup("open").enhanceWithin();
  /* close it */
  $("#popupID").popup("close");
  ```
- Statically

  ```
  <a href="#popupID" data-rel="popup">Popup</a>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

on page change or before calling the open function try putting it like this :

```
 $("#myDataPopUp").popup();
 $("#myDataPopUp").popup("open");
```