# Chrome bug, not opening jQuery Mobile popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

Based on an ajax login attempt, I try to display a popup if login fails. Works perfect in Firefox, but not showing in Chrome.
It's showing using Chrome debug, but not when run.

```
function loginUser(username, password)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: SERVER_URL + AJAX_FILE,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",
            data: { user:username, pass:password, func:"LOGIN" },
            success: function(data) {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(json.LOGIN);

                if (json.LOGIN === "LOGIN_OK") {
                    $.mobile.navigate("#start", { transition : "fade" });
                }
                else {
                    $("#popupLoginFail").popup("open");
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("Unknown error " + data);
            }
        });
    }
```

And popup looks like:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLoginFail" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
                <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                    <h3 class="ui-title">Unable to login</h3>
                <p>Wrong username or password</p>
                    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Ok</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `dataType: "text"`, then why you use this `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Try escaping the current context by issuing `window.setTimeout(function() { $("#popupLoginFail").popup("open"); }, 10);`. No guarantees, but that solved similar problems for me.

Comment: To get the .LOGIN variable

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No difference :-(

Comment: make sure you dont get "access-control-allow-origin" error. FF works fine, but chrome not.

Comment: @Omar I don't see any errors in the console window.

Comment: is popup's direct parent `data-role=page`?

Comment: No it's in `<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="loginp">` But tried both, no difference

Comment: it should be outside any div, direct parent should be page div. or convert it into an external popup by placing it outside any page div

Comment: Haven't tried it outside the page div...

Comment: if you use external popup, you need to initialize it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22910825/1771795

Comment: Makes no difference. Chrome closes the popup automaticly. It's showing in debug, but I think the close event is called automaticly

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Didn't work with 10ms, but 1000ms delay is fine. Seems to work now.... `window.setTimeout(function() { $("#popupLoginFail").popup("open"); }, 1000);`

Comment: Wish I could do a preventDefault(); somehow on the popup....